# Nativescript how to handle tel: and mailto: protocols from webview?

Tags: javascript, webview, nativescript, mailto, tel

I have been checking almost all night. All the examples do not work. Is there a way to capture a anchor tag click for tel: or mailto: from a webview? I was pointed to some webview plugins on market.nativescript.org but there is no example of how to accomplish that task. I am using Nativescript core.

[Nativescript Webview Open Url In Default Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355666/nativescript-webview-open-url-in-default-browser) does not work. The pages is loaded just the same when the link is clicked/tapped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NativeScript WebView open url in default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355666/nativescript-webview-open-url-in-default-browser)

Comment: Manoj, that does not work. Please see the edited question above.

Comment: It works on my end. If you have issues, please share a Playground sample.